# Does "the functions agree at infinity" mean anything?

Tags: general-topology, limits, functions, reference-request, asymptotics

I want a way to describe how two continuous functions $f,g \colon (X-x) \to Y$ might "share a limit" at the point $x$ when unfortunately neither of $\displaystyle \lim _{y \to x}f(x)$ or $\displaystyle \lim _{y \to x}g$ happen to exist..

Let me give an example. Suppose $x = 0$ and $f,g \colon (0,1] \to \mathbb R$ are given by $f = \sin(1/x)$ and $g = \sin(1/x) +x$. Then for any prescribed $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $\delta > 0$ such that, when I restrict the functions to the ball $B(0,\delta)$ their graphs are within distance $\epsilon$ of each other.

However in this case it's a lot easier. We can just take the difference of the functions $(f-g)(x) =x$ and say that function tends to zero at $x$. But this relies on how the real line has an additive structure. If we replace the codomain with something more exotic this definition might not apply.

So how might I formalise this notion of "agreeing at infinity" for more general topological spaces $Y$?

Comment: Perhaps [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) are what you're looking for.

Comment: I think most people would call the notion you've defined "agreeing at $x$," not agreeing at infinity. The object of the preposition "at" is an element of the domain, not the codomain. (As you said yourself, you want their difference to decay to zero "at $x$.")

Comment: In this case "infinity" is neither an element of the domain or codomain. Of course if the example was modified to have domain $(-\infty,1)$ rather than $(0,1]$ it would be more transparent why the name is chosen.

Comment: I see how this could immediately generalise to uniform spaces. But can we go any further than that?!

Comment: @Daron: I confess I didn't read your specific example. I guessed you were going to say something like $1/x^2$ and $1/2x^2$ agreed at infinity. My point is that most people take "agreeing at infinity" to mean something about limits as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Symplectomorphic: No, those two functions do not agree at zero in the same sense as my example, because the distance between the graphs of $1/x^2$ and $1/2x^2$ increases cubically as we approach the point.

Comment: @Daron What confuses me is that every topological space has open sets, so why don't you just use the first definition

Comment: @Daron: yes, I was confessing I thought you had another example in mind, and that that example was why you chose the language "at infinity." I agree the example I just gave does not satisfy your condition. You are missing the bigger point: the terminology of two functions "agreeing at infinity" is already reserved for asymptotic equivalence as $x\to\infty$, and it's hard to see why you use the language "at infinity" in the title of the question when your post is about limits **at $x$**.

Comment: Perhaps the language would make more sense if you cast the example as the agreement of $\sin x$ and $\sin x+1/x$ as $x\to\infty$. In any case, I'll leave it there.

Comment: Yes, I agree the terminology "agree at infinity" is already occupied by asymptotic behaviour. Probably I had heard it before but not remembered what it means. Nevertheless the question stands